# Add timeout to jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, knockout.js, timeout

I've inherited the following as part of a `knockout.js` grid.

It fills a grid with search results when you click the image input.

I would like to have it reload the page if the server times out (say 30 seconds) but I am very new to `jQuery` and am not sure where to start.

I can see a  `success`  in the code, and have found plenty of resources on timing things, but not sure what to test for or where to test it etc.

Please advise if you can and thank you in advance!

```
self.submitSearch = function () {
    $("#foundMembersTableParent").block({ message: '<img src="/Content/images/spinnerLarge.gif" /> Searching...' });
    self.selectedMembers.removeAll();
    fnOnSearch();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Members/MSearch',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: self.getFormData(),
        success: function (data) {
            self.members($.map(data.searchResults, function (item) { return new Members(item) }));
            $("#foundMembersTableParent").unblock();
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

self.getFormData = function () {
    var frmobj = $('#complexSearchForm').serializeObject();
    return JSON.stringify(frmobj);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `timeout` and an `error` handler to your `ajax` request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Members/MSearch',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: self.getFormData(),
    success: function (data) {
        self.members($.map(data.searchResults, function (item) { return new Members(item) }));
        $("#foundMembersTableParent").unblock();
    },
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 30000,      // 30 seconds
    error: function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (textStatus === "timeout") {
            // request timed out, do whatever you need to do here
        }
        else {
            // some other error occurred
        }
    }
});
```

See the docs: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As a wild guess, I think you are probably using this plugin:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element

In which case, in your `error` handler, all you'd really need to do is:

```
$("#foundMembersTableParent").unblock();
```

To restore functionality to your grid. Of course, you might also want to bring up and error message somewhere so the user understands why the table didn't change.

Comment: the timeout won't reload the grid it will just stop if the query takes too long.

Comment: @user3360944: No - that's why I left a comment where the OP can put whatever code they want for handling reloading. They actually said "reload the page" which I doubt is literally what they want.

Comment: I think they could easily add window.location.reload() in the error handling, if that is "literally what they want", but they should let the user know somehow that the request timed out.

Comment: @user3360944: Actually, I suspect all they need to do is remove whatever loading screen is introduced by this line `$("#foundMembersTableParent").block` (I assume block is from some kind of jQuery plugin) and maybe popup a message saying it timed out. They could also maybe restore whatever was in `self.selectedMembers`, but without more context, it's hard to say.

Comment: I almost had it from Matt's first comment when I saw he expanded on his answer. Come to find out the other code was still returning an empty json string so I also had to test parse my return data in the success function. I was adding an alert message to the TempData but needed to reload the page to get the user to see it. Thanx again!